# how do you dynamically insert console logs on a development server

Tags: merge, localhost, development-environment, production-environment, pull-request

When you're developing on localhost, then you've got full access to a terminal that you can log anywhere you want. But, in a project, I work on (and am new to team collaboration as a whole) they use something called `weavescope` to view logs that developers have created at the time of coding.

Now what the difference between this and logging locally, everytime you'll create a change in the code, you gotta send a pull request, they approve it, and merge it, deploy it and we finally see it in the log. Now, sometimes the state of local and deployed things don't match and it really makes us wanna dynamically log on to the development server without having to go through all these cycles over again. Is there any solution already around that helps us insert some quick log statements without having to go through the routine PR, merge, deploy cycle?

EDIT: I think from discussions I had below, the tool I am looking for is more or less a logging statment code injection tool. A tool that would keep track of the logs I'm inserting into the production code, and on/off them at spin of a command.

Comment: What information are you wanting to record in your logging environment without making any changes to code? Also, my understanding is that weavescope is a no-code monitoring tool for Docker and Kubernetes, not a logging tool for code changes.

Comment: @TylerH, No, I mean changing the code is good, but, if a tool really allowed us to insert logs on the fly after it's been deployed. Yeah, weavescope is monitoring tool, but, it does facilitate in viewing logs. I didn't mean logging them with weavescope

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something that logging levels can help with (unless I'm misunderstanding). Something I typically do is leave debug-level log messages on commonly problematic or complex functions, but change the logging level to something higher when I move out of local. Sometimes depending on the app and access these can be configured at the environment rather than in the build.

For example there are Spring libraries that will let you import a static logger, set the level of each message you log out. Then locally you can keep the level at `DEBUG`, in UAT the level can be `INFO`, and if you only want `ERROR` OR `WARN` messages in prod you can separate that too. At the time of deployment you can set what environment it is and store a separate app.properties or yml file for each environment storing the desired level for each

Comment: yes, but, that's not very dynamic. I can't add logs after it's been deployed to uat, As you say(If I understood it correctly) I'll have to make the log locally, enable 'em for UAT and deploy them

Comment: Oh I see. I don’t think what you’re describing is possible.  Unless you provided an injection point between each line  of code you write pointing to like a unique environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a solution for fast pace code changes.

Maybe [this](https://nimblewebdeveloper.com/blog/hot-reload-nodejs-server/) kind of hot reloading is what you're looking for. This way you can insert new calls to a logger or `console.log` quickly.
Although it does come with a disclaimer from the author.

> I honestly haven't looked into whether this method of hot reloading would provide stable production zero-downtime deploys, however my "gut feel" says don't do it. And production deployments are probably one area where we should stick to known, trusted procedures unless we have good reason.

Comment: um... as far I understand the article linked, it seems the author is talking about a solution for hot reloading in his local nodejs server. But, what I'm looking for is more or less a code injection tool, that would let us dynamically inject log statements on the fly.